# Laravel Pivot table relationship between 3 tables

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, has-many

I have a pivot table with the following columns:

```
product_id
product_attribute_id
product_attribute_value_id
```

A product can have many Attributes, and through this Attribute has many AttributeValues.

For example, an Attribute could be Colour, which has Red, Blue, Green and Yellow as AttributeValues.

However, a T Shirt product could have the Attribute of Colour, but only Red and Blue are selected as AttributeValues.

What I'm trying to do is, based on this pivot table get all of the Attributes and the AttributeValues based on a specific product ID.

I've tried using a hasManyDeep package (https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep), which has got me so far as I can get a collection of the AttributeValues but not in the format which I require.

The package gives me an array of AttributeValues, each has the Attribute relationship. What I need is an array of Attributes, each with the AttributeValues.

Here's what I've tried so far with the package:

```
return $this->hasManyDeep(
        ProductAttributeValue::class,
        [ProductOptionValue::class, ProductAttribute::class],
        ['product_id', 'id', 'product_attribute_id'],
        ['id', 'product_attribute_id', 'id'])
        ->whereColumn('product_attribute_values.id', '=', 'product_product_option_values.product_attribute_value_id')
        ->withIntermediate(ProductAttribute::class, ['*'], 'attribute');
```

**EDIT**

I have then tried to switch the query around so that I am getting the ProductAttribute first as @JonasStaudenmeir suggested, but this isn't working properly.

```
return $this->hasManyDeep(
        ProductAttribute::class,
        [ProductOptionValue::class, ProductAttributeValue::class],
        ['product_id', 'id', 'id'],
        ['id', 'product_attribute_value_id', 'product_attribute_id'])
        ->whereColumn('product_attributes.id', '=', 'product_product_option_values.product_attribute_id')
        ->withIntermediate(ProductAttributeValue::class, ['*'], 'attribute');
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191508/discussion-on-question-by-karl-laravel-pivot-table-relationship-between-3-tables). If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] it into your question, rather than replying in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to get the result you need without calling to many methods.

You can make a normal relation (hasOne / hasMany) and call the relation thru the relation it self because the relation will be connected. So lets say you want to get the value of the products you can loop thru all the products `$product->attribute` then you can call the the product's value `$attribute->product_attribute_value->{value you need to have}`

Hope this helps. Good luck